# Can I use specific expected values in a chi-squared test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio

EDIT: More context in experiment, hypotheses, and more clarity in my questions. TL;DR below.

Fifty participants completed two similar tasks under three conditions:

- No distraction
- Low distraction
- High distraction

A theory suggests both tasks measure the same mechanism. In addition, the theory says performance on both tasks will be highest in the no distraction condition, followed by the low distraction condition, with lowest performance in the high distraction condition.

I have already tested the following predictions on the continuous scores:

- Performance on no dist. > lo dist. > hi dist. in Task 1 [TRUE]
- Performance on no dist. > lo dist. > hi dist. in Task 2 [TRUE]
- Performance on the two tasks will be correlated for each condition [FALSE]

Since the third prediction was incorrect using the continuous scores, I've decided to take an additional approach and reduce this data down to frequencies.

These are my observed values for 'best' scores:

```
Best Score           Best Score in Task 1
in Task 2      No Dist.      Lo Dist.      Hi Dist.
No Dist.          12            5             1    
Lo Dist.          14            8             2
Hi Dist.           4            3             1
```

And my observed values for 'worst' scores:

```
Worst Score           Worst Score in Task 1
in Task 2      No Dist.      Lo Dist.      Hi Dist.
No Dist.           1            2             4    
Lo Dist.           1            2             5
Hi Dist.           6            4            25
```

And mosaic plots for these values, where tile area relates to participant frequency:

[image: Observed data]

I'd like to test the hypotheses:

- More participants will achieve their best scores in both tasks in the 'no distraction' condition, than in the 'low distraction' condition; (1,1) > (2,2)
- Less participants will achieve their best scores in both tasks in the 'high distraction' condition, than in the 'low distraction' condition; (3,3) < (2,2)
- More participants will achieve their worst scores in both tasks in the 'high distraction' condition, than in the 'low distraction' condition; (3,3) > (2,2)
- Less participants will achieve their worst scores in both tasks in the 'no distraction' condition, than in the 'low distraction' condition; (1,1) < (2,2)

These hypotheses can be visualised with the mosaic plots below (n.b. arbitrary values).

[image: Expected data]

A classic chi-squared test of independence would not answer my specific hypotheses. In fact they suggest best/worst scores on the two tasks to be independent.

If the exact values from these plots are used, my expected values for best scores would be:

```
Best Score           Best Score in Task 1
in Task 2      No Dist.      Lo Dist.      Hi Dist.
No Dist.         12.5          8.3          4.2    
Lo Dist.          8.3          5.5          2.8
Hi Dist.          4.2          2.8          1.4
```

And for worst scores would be the inverse:

```
Worst Score           Worst Score in Task 1
in Task 2      No Dist.      Lo Dist.      Hi Dist.
No Dist.          1.4          2.8          4.2    
Lo Dist.          2.8          5.5          8.3
Hi Dist.          4.2          8.3         12.5
```

However, the magnitude of the frequencies in these plots are arbitrary. It's the relative proportions between conditions that are important. Therefore, testing these specific expected values may not be fair.

**My questions:** (TL;DR)

1. Can I use specific expected values in a chi-squared test?

   - If so, would it be fair to use the arbitrary values in the latter two tables?
2. Should I test against strong and weak versions of the hypothesis, in terms of expected values?

   - If so, could I compare their fits somehow? e.g. a likelihood ratio test

Answer (score 3):

I would relax your null hypothesis a bit. I would say that there are people who switch condition, and when they do they will follow an independence model (what you test with a standard $\chi^2$-test), but that there is also a substantial portion of the respondents that remain on the diagonals. This is a classic hypothesis in [log-linear analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-linear_analysis).

You test that by estimating two models: one that is only an independence model, and one that adds parameters for the diagonals. The exponentiated diagonal parameters are the factors by which the counts in the diagonal cells increase due to the people who choose to stay on the diagonal cells (or if they are smaller than 1, choose to avoid the diagonal cells): the expected number of people in the diagonal cell 1,1 increases by a factor 1.5 compared to an independence model due the people that *per se* want to remain in a diagonal cell.  Then we compare the two models with a likelihood ratio test. In your data we canot reject the hypothesis that there is nothing special about the diagonal.

Here is how I would do this in Stata:

```
. // prepare the data
. clear

. input task1 task2 freq

         task1      task2       freq
  1. 1 1 12
  2. 1 2  5
  3. 1 3  1
  4. 2 1  4
  5. 2 2  3
  6. 2 3  1
  7. 3 1 14
  8. 3 2  8
  9. 3 3  2
 10. end

.
. gen diag = (task1==task2)*task1

.
. // look at the data
. tabdisp task1 task2, c(freq)

----------------------------
          |      task2
    task1 |    1     2     3
----------+-----------------
        1 |   12     5     1
        2 |    4     3     1
        3 |   14     8     2
----------------------------

. tabdisp task1 task2, c(diag)

----------------------------
          |      task2
    task1 |    1     2     3
----------+-----------------
        1 |    1     0     0
        2 |    0     2     0
        3 |    0     0     3
----------------------------

.
. // test whether diagonals are more common than
. // we would expect under an independence model
.
. // the independence model
. poisson freq i.task1 i.task2, irr

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -14.980851
Iteration 1:   log likelihood =  -14.95665
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -14.956607
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -14.956607

Poisson regression                              Number of obs     =          9
                                                LR chi2(4)        =      31.07
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -14.956607                     Pseudo R2         =     0.5095

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        freq |        IRR   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       task1 |
          2  |   .4444444   .1888526    -1.91   0.056     .1932531    1.022136
          3  |   1.333333   .4157397     0.92   0.356     .7236524    2.456674
             |
       task2 |
          2  |   .5333333   .1651038    -2.03   0.042     .2907319    .9783739
          3  |   .1333333   .0709721    -3.79   0.000     .0469734    .3784647
             |
       _cons |       10.8   2.834643     9.07   0.000     6.456713    18.06492
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. est store independence

.
. // allow diagonals to be different
. poisson freq i.task1 i.task2 i.diag, irr

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -14.724323
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -14.672566
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -14.672395
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -14.672395

Poisson regression                              Number of obs     =          9
                                                LR chi2(7)        =      31.64
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -14.672395                     Pseudo R2         =     0.5188

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        freq |        IRR   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       task1 |
          2  |   .5506669   .3871607    -0.85   0.396     .1388128    2.184481
          3  |   1.759949   .9537229     1.04   0.297     .6084581    5.090604
             |
       task2 |
          2  |   .6046409    .256736    -1.18   0.236      .263069    1.389714
          3  |   .1655643    .137213    -2.17   0.030     .0326231    .8402489
             |
        diag |
          1  |    1.54041   1.011098     0.66   0.510     .4255227    5.576352
          2  |   1.156618   .9645865     0.17   0.861      .225586    5.930179
          3  |   .8810864   .9542909    -0.12   0.907     .1054618    7.361081
             |
       _cons |   7.790132   4.592245     3.48   0.000     2.453384    24.73569
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. est store diag

.
. // test the two models agains one another
. lrtest diag independence

Likelihood-ratio test                                 LR chi2(3)  =      0.57
(Assumption: independence nested in diag)             Prob > chi2 =    0.9036
```

Comment: Thanks for your very thorough answer. I haven't used Stata before and have never performed a likelihood ratio test, so your walkthrough is very helpful. 

I have some questions:
1) Why would we expect a ratio of 1.5?
2) What specific hypothesis does this test, and what would be the null?

Comment: 1) that is the empirical finding: In the last model you see the first exponentiated diag coefficient is 1.54041. In the text I interpreted that parameter. 2) The exponentiated diag coefficient are all 1 (the diag coefficients are all 0).

Comment: The explanation should now be clearer.

Comment: You don't need to use Stata for that. Any program that can estimate a poisson regression will do. I am just most comfortable with Stata.

Comment: Thanks again, Maarten. More Qs: a) Is the independence model the second table in my question? b) How would that hypothesis be worded in relation to my research question? You said I should relax my null, but I'm not sure what you mean. c) Do you have any links for using likelihood ratio tests / poisson regressions in this way? I spent yesterday googling but a lot of it didn't seem relevant.

Comment: Why are the diagonals 1, 2 and 3, rather than all the same number, e.g. 1?

Comment: There is a link in my answer, which in turn has references and suggestions for further reading.

Comment: If you give them the same number than that is a restriction of the model. That may or may not be useful. In my context (homogamy: education of ego and education of partner) it makes more sense to allow the diagonals to be different. Empirically you diagonals seem to differ as well.

Comment: The independence model is your second table

Comment: The diagonals model assumes that there are two types of persons: some choose there conditions in task 1 and 2 according to an independence model and some will choose their conditions in task 1 and 2 such that they will always remain on the diagonal. The null hypothesis is that there are only people who choose their condition based on the independence model.

Comment: So I am comparing the likelihood that model A (diagonal people plus independence people) fits my data, with the likelihood that model N (just independence people) fits my data? Would it be possible to compare the likelihood that model B (just diagonal people) fits my data with the likelihood that model N fits my data, as that is my hypothesis?

Comment: That model would not be nested in the idependence model. So we canot compare those models with a likelihood ratio test.

Comment: In general a model without the margins is possible, but almost always a bad idea. Very much like modeling an interaction effect without the main effects is possible, but almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks again, Maarten. I see. So the closest I can get to the question "Are participants' best scores on two different tasks in the same condition?", is to ask "Are some participants' best scores on two different tasks in the same condition, while others' best scores are in different conditions?"? It seems like the only answer to this question could be yes - some will generally stay on the diagonal, while others will  move away from it. Perhaps that isn't the question that this likelihood ratio test is testing.

Comment: The last piece of the puzzle for me is grasping the specific research question this LRT is testing, in terms of my research question. Could you word it in terms of best score, tasks and conditions?

Comment: The null hypothesis is: There are more people on the diagonal than you would expect under the independence model.

Comment: Why is that the null and not the research hypothesis? Wouldn't the null just be the independence model?

Comment: Absolutely, my bad

Comment: Hi again, Maarten. I'm just writing up my results, and wanted to check the wording with you:

First, a Poisson regression was performed to calculate the likelihood that the model with greater frequencies on the diagonal fits the observed data. Next, a second Poisson regression was conducted to calculate the likelihood that the null hypothesis (random, independent distribution of participants) fits the observed data. Finally, a likelihood ratio test compared the log likelihoods of each model.

Comment: However, for both best performance and worst performance, the diagonal model did not explain the data significantly better than the null (χ2(3) = 0.57, p = .904 and χ2(3) = 1.74, p = .627 respectively.

Is the above adequate, or are the log likelihoods of each model usually reported? I'm also not sure whether I should say Poisson regression or log-linear analysis - does it matter? Thank you.

Comment: Using a likelihood ratio test implies you estimated two model. All you need to do is mention them. The models a log-linear models, Poisson regression is just the method of estimating them. So would say something like: This hypothesis was tested by comparing a quasi-independence model against an independence model using a likelhood ratio test, and the results are ... so in both cases we could not reject the independence model. This presumes you discussed the models earlier in your methods section.

Comment: Excellent, thanks again Maarten! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Maarten, I've just found that I'd accidentally confused two columns in my data file! I've updated my question with the correct data, and included the data for worst performance too. It's been suggested that performance should be best in condition 1 and worst in condition 3, and this looks more likely now. Is there a way to include this in the quasi-independence model?

Comment: Specifically: (1) There will be more people on the diagonal than not, and (2) In the diagonal cells, [3,3] will be more frequent, and [1,1] less frequent, in terms of worst performance. When I used your code above with the corrected worst data, the p-value actually increased from 0.627 to 0.808, though it looks like a better fit.

Comment: Is this achievable? I know for the nested test to work, the two models need to differ by only one parameter. Can the parameter deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can test that hypothesis directly with a chi-square goodness of fit. Each cell of your design is a cell with a hypothesized proportion (this is what the test of independence is doing anyway, it just is coming up with a way of combining the marginals to come up with the appropriate proportions assuming independence).

Using raw counts...

$ \chi^2 = \Sigma\frac{(O - E)^2}{E} $

Where O is your observed count under the null and E is your expected count.  Although it should be noted that E will fall apart under expectations of 0 (and generally chi-square doesn't perform well with low count cells... so some allowances may need to be made... a hypothesized proportion of 0 is a pretty extreme hypothesis).

Comment: Thanks RPierce! So I could come up with fairer expected values, and use a chi-square goodness of fit test?

Comment: So if the expected values are a good fit, chi-square would return a non-significant result? Is there an alpha criterion for poor fit? Perhaps I could combine your answer with Maarten's and do compare the fits of an independence model with a model with specified expected values.

Comment: The expected values are your null hypothesis, so deviation from expectation will lead to a higher chisq which in turn lead to a lower p value.  In short, in a goodness of fit test a low p value reflects a statistically sig deviation from the tested hypothesis. Like any statistical test alpha is a matter of purpose, tast, and tradition.

Comment: When I was reading up I saw: "The chi-square goodness of fit test is applied when you have one categorical variable from a single population. It is used to determine whether sample data are consistent with a hypothesized distribution." Did you mean the chi-square test of independence? In which case, I'd like to compare the relative likelihoods of the null hypothesis, and a specific hypothesis.

Comment: That is an excessively restrictive description of the Goodness of Fit test IMO.  I did mean Goodness of Fit (Independence is the same test just with the expected values parameterized by the marginal counts).

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. Is there a way to compare the fit of a null chi-square (my second table) with the fit of a relaxed version of my second table?

Comment: You can always relax the hypothesis you are testing by ascribing values of E that are closer to those provided by the test of independence.  

Taking a giant step backwards... you do realize that with a hypothesis test you can only reject the null, right?  I think very much that the test of independence is your first stop.  

Next you'd want to make some claim regarding the validity of your diagonality hypothesis.  What null hypothesis, when refuted, provides support for the hypothesis of interest?  Can you express it in expected values versus observed values?

Comment: From what I've seen you've only stated that you don't like the form of the null hypothesis under a test for independence, but you haven't provided a sense of what a more reasonable null would be / how another null, if rejected, would support your diagonality hypothesis more strongly.

Comment: Thanks again RPierce. I've edited my question to answer your queries. After more thought on the theory's predictions, larger values on the diagonal is not necessarily true.